# Looking for IDE compiler to build and run a .c source file without creating a project

Tags: c, ide, alternative, code-blocks

I have ubuntu 12.04 and KDE.

I already know **Code::BLocks** that does the job, but I have a problem with it: any version of it (12.11 or 10.05) I use doesn't close when I click the close button and if i try to make any change to editor setting it's not saved. 
So I'm looking for a IDE compiler for c programs that does the same job with c source file.
I need it for university, my teacher uses **Dev-C++** for windows but I have ubuntu and I need something similar to open a .c source and build and run it as faster as I can.
If there are no ide like codeblocks maybe something like **eclipse**, **netbeans**, **codelite** etc... have a plugin to build a .c source without making a project I don't know. 
Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to quickly do one file program, I use any text editor and compile from the command line. I use emacs, but any editor will do. gedit is the editor that ubuntu comes installed with. From the terminal type `gedit test.c &` then to compile it use `gcc test.c -o test`

Answer (score 0):

most of the IDE require to create a project because it needs additional information like with which libraries the program should be linked etc.
I use geany to compile a single file and Qt Creator for project, it is a nice IDE but you will need to create project.
You can use geany as default program for opening .c file.

Comment: ok thanks, I know about geany, it's good but is there any ide that does the same thing somehow? because a graphical ide would be go even when I'll need to make projects, so I need a program that does both things.

Comment: I found anjuta 3.4 on repository. I downloaded the plugins and now i can compile a .c source file BUT I can't run it because when I run it a "program parameters" windows opens in which I can insert aguments, program, environment variables, execute in terminal etc... and I don't know what to do. Any help?